# .NET Library Project whit FrameWork 4.7.2, Only not work on my pc and when I run the compiled project

Tags: .net, dll, frameworks, .net-assembly

I have a .NET Library Project witt FrameWork 4.7.2, the problem I have is that "Only on my pc and when I run the compiled project (the DLL), it throws me the following error message" --> "failed with the following message: Object reference not set as an instance of an object."

Well this project is installed as an Add-in in Navision BC 14, but it is still a library in .NET a DLL with functions.

So, I think i have the problem in calling the system.xml.dll .dll, and once the project is compiled, it does not call te correct version of System.xml.dll what i use.

What I would like is:

**To be able to force my project, only use the referenced (.DLL )libraries.**

Now I put the tests and cases that I have been doing for make this work, in a nutshell:

**Does not work when**:

- install as Add-in Navision on my machine

**If it works in**:

- Debug mode from the .NET project
- Generating the application as .exe (program) and ejecting it from my PC.
- Other machines like Navision Add-in do work.
- If I unmake a call to the system.xml.dll library (this is exactly what I need for the development functionality .. create and digitally sign an XML.).

  `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();`
  `doc.Load(xmldata);`

Entire code is:

```
        var xmldata = _XMLFacturae.XMLDIR + _XMLFacturae.XMLNAME;
        string text = File.ReadAllText(xmldata);
        text = text.Replace("<Facturae", "<fe:Facturae xmlns:ds='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' xmlns:fe='http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2014/v3.2.1/Facturae'");
        text = text.Replace("</Facturae", "</fe:Facturae");
        File.WriteAllText(xmldata, text);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmldata);
```

**Things I've done without success, to try to make it work on my machine:**

- Reinstall Framework.
- DISM.exe / Online / Cleanup-image / Restorehealth
- sfc / scannow

**In the project:**

- References / Copy = true of system.xml.dll
- Add on appconfig

  ```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns = "urn: schemas-microsoft-com: asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <probing privatePath = "bin \ Debug \ libs \" />
  ```

Como "Reference / copy local = TRUE", i copy and paste the DLLS, relative address to directory to the "bin \ Debug \ libs "

- Same as before but renaming DLL from system.xml.dll to system.xml2.dll
- Throw the pc out the window XD, not just joke.

Comment: Maybe I missed something (I don't use .NET or DLLs as such so maybe I'm not getting something), but what does this have to do with assembly language? (I saw this question through the [assembly] tag)

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: In .NET, "an assembly" is what they call a library, similar in concept to a Java `.jar` I think.  We get a couple questions a week that need their tags edited (by one of the high-rep users who follow the assembly tag) from `[.net] [assembly]` to `[.net-assembly]`.  (Possibly also keeping .net as a separate tag, if there isn't something like C#).  There's also an [tag:assemblies] tag, but AFAIK it should just be a synonym for [tag:.net-assembly].

Comment: @PeterCordes I see, I hadn't known that. I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks.